# How to configure automatic time-based Redis cache invalidation in NestJS if I use cache manager?

Tags: caching, redis, nestjs

I'm working on a NestJS project that provides a weather API. I use NestJS cache manager instead of a native Redis driver.

Here is my `cache` module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { RedisOptions } from './config/redis.config';

@Module({
  imports: [CacheModule.registerAsync(RedisOptions)]
})
export class AppCacheModule {}
```

Here is my Redis config:

```
import { CacheModuleAsyncOptions } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { redisStore } from 'cache-manager-redis-store';

export const RedisOptions: CacheModuleAsyncOptions = {
  isGlobal: true,
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const store = await redisStore({
      socket: {
        host: configService.get<string>('REDIS_HOST'),
        port: parseInt(configService.get<string>('REDIS_PORT'))
      }
    });
    return {
      store: () => store
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService]
};
```

And that's how I use the cache manager in my weather service:

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

import { FullWeatherData } from 'src/weather/api/types';
import { WeatherApiService } from 'src/weather/provider/weather.provider.interface';

/**
 * Service handling weather-related business logic.
 *
 * @class
 */
@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  /**
   * Creates an instance of WeatherService.
   *
   * @constructor
   * @param {WeatherApiService} weatherApi - An instance of the weather API provider.
   *   Injected based on the configured provider token.
   */
  constructor(
    @Inject('WeatherApiService') private weatherApi: WeatherApiService,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache
  ) {}

  /**
   * Retrieves weather data by latitude and longitude.
   *
   * @public
   * @async
   * @param {number} lat - The latitude coordinate.
   * @param {number} lon - The longitude coordinate.
   * @returns {Promise<FullWeatherData>} A promise that resolves to the retrieved weather data.
   */
  public async getWeatherData(lat: number, lon: number): Promise<FullWeatherData> {
    const cacheKey = this.getCacheKey(lat, lon);
    const cachedData = await this.cacheManager.get<FullWeatherData | undefined>(
      cacheKey
    );

    if (cachedData) {
      return cachedData;
    }

    const data: FullWeatherData = await this.weatherApi.getWeatherData(lat, lon);
    this.cacheManager.set(cacheKey, data);

    return data;
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a cache key based on provided latitude and longitude.
   *
   * @param {number} lat – Latitude.
   * @param {number} lon – Longitude.
   * @returns {string} Cache key.
   */
  private getCacheKey(lat: number, lon: number): string {
    return `${lat}:${lon}`;
  }
}
```

For now the data saved to the cache is stored in there permanently. What I want to do is to configure Redis and/or cache manager to automatically invalidate data that is stored in the cache for longer than 30 seconds.

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

cache manager has a optional property called ttl (time to live), in the latest versions they changed the value to accept in milliseconds so it would be better to check your current version first.

in your case it would be like this:

```
await this.cacheManager.set(cacheKey, data, 30000);
```

it's better to set some const to reuse it or maybe put it on your .env instead of passing the value through the param if you are going to use it more than once

read more about this on the official docs
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching